# R a collection of kmeans objects

Tags: r, list, collections, vector, k-means

I am new to R and most of my experience is in Java. I am trying to do the following:

```
clusterWeeks <- function()
{
  kmV = list()               #a list of kmeans objects from each week
  for(i in 1:5)
  {
    windows()
    kmV.append(clusterData(i))     #clusterData(i) returns a kmeans object
  }
}
```

For some reason this does not work. I would like to then be able to access the objects via `kmV[1], kmV[2], ... kmV[5]`

1. What is the appropriate data structure in R for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a list to hold each separate object. Otherwise you are just overwriting and returning only the last one:

```
clusterWeeks <- function()
{
  kmV = vector("list", 5)         # a 5 element list of empty items
  for(i in 1:5)
  {
    windows()
    kmV[[i]] <- clusterData(i)    #clusterData(i) returns a kmeans object
  }
}
```

You are obviously coming from a language where `object.function` is an acceptable syntax, but that does not work in R.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, here is what I would do:

```
clusterWeeks <- function(){
  kmV <- c()
  for(i in 1:5)
  {
    kmV <- c(kmV, i)
  }
  return(kmV)
}
```

small example:

```
test <- clusterWeeks()
test[2]
2
```

Comment: Using `c(old, new)` would be fine for small lists but if the list has already been pre-allocated it is more efficient to assign by location.